# I'm getting errors in GIMP, so what's a good batch photo processing program that can replicate GIMP's auto white balance?

Tags: image-processing, gimp

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm having trouble batch processing images in GIMP because I'm getting the following error:

```
While parsing XMP metadata:
Error: No XMP packet found
```

I've researched the problem on the web and it appears like it's a problem with the EXIF metadata. I'm using a Sony camera (the A6000), and it apparently does not save the images with this "XMP packet" that GIMP is looking for.

So considering this, can anyone suggest a photo program/utility that can (1) process images in batches; and (2), replicate what GIMP's "auto white balance" does, because that tool really makes the image "pop out" and improve more often than not.

EDIT: I've tried ImageMagick and the tools it has does not produce the same effect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250409/imagemagick-auto-adjust-the-colours-of-an-image-a-la-other-photo-management-ap

Comment: I've tried ImageMagick and the tools it has doesn't produce the same effect...

Comment: Maybe post an *unhappy* image and a *happy, GIMPed-up* image so we can see what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

I get this error when batch processing images straight out of my Nikon DSLR.
I believe that images straight out of a camera will not have any XMP data, and getting this error message is the correct behavior.

You can check if there is xmp data with exiftool:
"exiftool -xmp -a [filename]"

It seems to be actually a harmless warning message, and not an actual error that stops the batch processing. The task I have coded for (desaturating the image) still completes. Is this error actually preventing your script from doing the task(s) at hand?

If so, you can try adding in XMP data with the exiftool. I have not done this.